# Apple In App Purchase working only on store version, and not working on xcode build after updating to iOS 16

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, ios16

I'm restoring purchase for the account, when I call       SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions() to get the completed transactions, none of the delegate or observer methods are called, which are working well on pre iOS 16, and this happens when running application using xcode.

-When I tried the store version, and tried to restore purchases, It is working fine on iOS 16

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. When I try to purchase it prompts for the payment, but - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions for SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased is never called. Are you having this issue as well?

Answer (score 1):

We hit this same issue. The 'fix' on our end is to enable sandbox accounts on the devices that are running non-store builds.

Comment: I signed with sandbox on a real device, Are there steps to enable it, so we can fix this ?